# How to implement taskDidReceiveChallengeWithCompletion of session delegate in Alamofire 5

Tags: alamofire

How to upgrade taskDidReceiveChallengeWithCompletion present in alamofire 4.9.1 to 5.0.2.

Comment: What are your requirements? Why did you use the closure instead of the `ServerTrustManager`?

Comment: It's already implemented in code, I have to upgrade it to new one

Comment: I meant are you doing certificate pinning or something else?

Comment: Yes we are doing certificate pinning

Answer (score 0):

Certificate pinning in Alamofire 5 is done using the `ServerTrustManager`. At its simplest, you could implement it like this:

```swift
let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["my.domain.com": PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator()])
let session = Session(serverTrustManager: manager)
```

You can read more in our [`ServerTrustManager` docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#evaluating-server-trusts-with-servertrustmanager-and-servertrustevaluating).